# MVC : Can a service depend on other service?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I am pretty new working with the MVC pattern (Spring MVC). I have a very simple question. Can a service have a dependency on another service? something like:

```
@Service
public class MyFirstService{

   .....

   @Autowired
   private MySecondService secondService;

   ......
 }
```

Is this a "good practice" or is something that should be avoided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a simple answer: yes.

One service depending on another service makes sense. Else it is possible that you have code duplications.

One example that comes into mind is having an `EmailService`. I don't want to write email sending code several times so that I create a service out of this. This service would be called by other services naturally.

Comment: The EmailService is a great example. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. the expectation of service layer is to implement business logics of the application. assume that one business logic (implemented in one service) may need to use other service to do its operations. for example, LoanService module may access the InterestService to calculate the interest of the loan.

```
@Service
public class LoanService{

   .....

   @Autowired
   private InterestService interestService;

   ......
}
```